# Linux PC to PC Ethernet configuration

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I have two ARM target boards

How do I configure 2 such boards running Linux (Busybox) to communicate over Ethernet (pc to pc communication)  with each other ?

Can this be done using PC-to-Hub CAT-5 cables or do I necessarily need PC-to-PC / cross-connected cable ?

I tried with both the cross as well straight cables, I do not see LAN card link blinking, is there any configuration changes for Ethernet card that I need  to do here ?

If I try an connect one board to a PC both the ends can ping each other perfectly.

TIA

Comment: Did you set IP addresses from the same subnet? Did you use the [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) between the two PCs? Yes between PCs you have to use crossovers. Are the interfaces UP?

Comment: Without knowing what Network interface is built-in to your board, it is basically impossible to answer this.  Are you sure your cross-over cable is good?

Comment: @Alex Yes the IP were on same subnet, I tried both crossover as well straight cables.

Comment: What happens if you do create traffic, e.g. "ping 255.255.255.255"?

Comment: @Zoredache I am certain that the cable is good, since the same works between two desktop PCs correctly.

Comment: @MarcelWaldvogel : something specific about 255.255.255.255 ? since in board-to-board connection I do not see LAN card connection LEDs lit.

Comment: @Zoredache : what more information can help you with this ? Can I run some commands to get you that information ?

Comment: @Alex Do we have something similar on Linux ?

Comment: Sorry messed up there :) You can't be sure about that as PC NICs can have Auto-MDIX feature on them which makes it don't matter if it's a crossover or straight-through. And on your board you can have ones that don't have the support. So.. check the cable pinouts. You could get successful pings because of that feature (maybe you used the wrong cable still)

Comment: @Alex Checked the cable 1 X 3, 2 X 6 pins are crossed connected on two terminals

Comment: You can use ethtool to see if you have a link.  If it it available, it will also show you the MDI-X mode and allow you to change it.

Comment: @Ciclamino I tried it, that but unfortunately generic ethernet driver does not support reading/setting the MDIO line.

Comment: If it doesn't list MDI-X, then it probably doesn't support it.  ethtool should still be useful in telling you if you have a link, if there's no link detected, you know that's the level you need to troubleshoot at (and so you don't need to waste time with things like ip addresses).